# ASPX Control Injected Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a situation where I add several controls at runtime.  I do:

```
placeholder.Controls.Add(theaddedcontrol);
```

When I collect input from the page, I do not know how to access the added controls for their values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try placeholder.FindControl() passing in ID of the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following **structure**:

```
Control control = (Control) placeHolder.FindControl("ControlName");
Object targetProperty = control.//Target Property ...
```

---

Refer to [Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `Control.FindControl` method.

You can find more information on how to use this over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx)